# Auth Rules in Firebase

Tags: firebase-security

I am trying to use a basic rule to make sure only admin users can create and delete categories. Below is my rule:

```
{
    "rules": {
       "categories":{
         "$uid":{
          ".write": "root.child('Users').child($uid).child('isAdmin').exists()",
          ".read": true,
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 50"
         }
       }
}
}
```

but I still get a permission denied error.
Please what can I do about it?
Apologies if am doing it completely wrong, am new to firebase. Thanks

Comment: I think we need some more information here. What does your Firebase data structure look like? Are you sure your users node is called "Users" and node "users"? That typo alone might mess things up. Also, what does the code look like for the write you are trying to do? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: Also, you should be able to rewrite `"root.child('Users').child($uid).child('isAdmin').exists()"` as `"root.child('Users').child($uid).hasChild('isAdmin')"`.

Comment: my data structure looks like this: `{categories: {Tech:{'name':'tech'}}, users:{}}`. I am trying to use this code to do the write: `$scope.category = {};
  $scope.addCat = function(){
    var cat = ref.child('categories');
    cat.child($scope.category.name).set($scope.category)
  }`

Answer (score 3):

The `"Users"` node in your security rules does not match the casing of your `/users/` node in your data structure. Try changing the rule to:

".write": "root.child('**users**').child($uid).child('isAdmin').exists()"

Comment: I am still getting a permission denied error after making the change. I have also tried this: ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').exists()", but doesn't work too. Thanks

Comment: In the provided code, you are writing to `cat.child($scope.category.name).set($scope.category)`, which (according to your security rules) would mean that `$scope.category.name` is your `$uid`. I don't think this is what you want. Are you missing a `child(uid)` in there?